# Redirect parent page on Login cookie expiration

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a problem with server-side auto-redirection to a login page upon cookie timeout.
Our application uses a wrapper page (called "Application.aspx") which hold all our controls, as well as the rest of our application inside IFrames.

My problem occurs when the Login Cookie times out. The user should be looking at a Timeout warning screen in the form of a [RadWindow](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-overview.html) launched when their user-set lock time is reached. This screen exists until the global Authentication cookie expires. However, at that point, any action redirects only the RadWindow to the login, not the full application.

I have tried implementing a Response.Redirect("SessionTimeout.aspx,false); line to the globabl.aspx page in the AuthenticationRequest event. However, it appears somewhere along the line an Auto control is redirecting before my SessionTimeout page can execute its pageLoad.

Sadly, this is for a large company and I cannot share much exact code, but if anyone has found a way around this I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else finds this and needs the answer, I ended up creating a new cookie containing the expiry date of the original cookie.

I then checked if the current datetime was close to the value of the exp with jscript at regular intervals, and when it was within 30 seconds of expiring, redirected the user client-side.